# Nginx+PHP-FPM :: Connection Failed 502 while connecting to upstream

Tags: php, kubernetes, digital-ocean, nginx-ingress

I have tried to implement a structure when Nginx is the LB and Backend is PHP in Digital Ocean Kubernetes. Facing two issue

1. connection issue [though sometimes page is coming/sometimes got 502]

*502 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 10.244.1.219, server: staging.abc.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://10.245.111.210:9000", host: "staging.abc.com"

2. Connection is not secure though i have deployed Lets Encrypt Issuer only. [not clusterissuer]

> What I Have Done:

1. Create a Nginx Deployment, Service and Ingress

   ````
   kind: Ingress
   metadata:
     name: demo-ingress-2
     annotations:
       cert-manager.io/issuer: letsencrypt-mizan
   spec:
     ingressClassName: nginx
     tls:
     - hosts:
       - staging.abc.com
       secretName: letsencrypt-mizan
     rules:
     - host: staging.abc.com
       http:
         paths:
         - path: /
           pathType: Prefix
           backend:
             service:
               name: demo-service-2
               port:
                 number: 8080```
   ````

and **nginx conf**:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name staging.abc.com;

# Log files for Debug
error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;

# Laravel web root directory
root /var/www/html;
index index.php index.html;

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    gzip_static on;
}

# Nginx Pass requests to PHP-FPM
location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass **phpservice**:9000;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    client_max_body_size 256M;
}
}
```

2. Create another php Container with Deployment and Service with 9000 port.

So, When i give staging.abc.com in browser i am getting below issue:
[image: secure connection error]

And also getting 502 sometimes though i am using servicename of PHP Container in nginxconf.

**Traffic Flow:** staging.abc.com --> nginx pod --> php-fpm pod

Any Solution?

I am trying to get secure connection as well as getting PHP container through nginx.

Expecting:

Secure connection and No 502